# How can I sign a document using PKCS7, CAdES, S/MIME (e-cpf / e-cnpj) to create a P7S file using javascript on the browser?

Tags: javascript, x509, pki, pkcs#7, electronic-signature

I was able to read a p12 certificate file and, using the password, I was able to extract:

- `key` and `cert` using **forge** methods: `forge.pkcs12.pkcs12FromAsn1` and `getBags({friendlyName: this.selectedFriendlyName}).friendlyName`
- `privatePem` using `forge.pki.privateKeyToPem`

I found some solutions to sign a message or document using PKCS7, CAdES and S/MIME, but none of them produced a P7S file and the result is different than a proper P7S content (byte array), and that is what I understood is the correct file format to be used in E-CPF/E-CNPJ signed documents.

I would like to archive this using javascript on the browser, but any help or direction will be appreciated, thank you in advance :)

Comment: PKCS7 signature format have certificate or certificate chain. You may either build it on browser using JavaScript but if you don't get the code handy, you may calculate SignedData and post it separately along with Certificate to server and build CMS / PKCS#7 container on server.  Alternatively, you may use some Browser extension which provides PKCS#7 container. My Company. provides one such free extension. Search for Signer.Digital Chrome Extension.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are brazilian... Check if this PHP answer helps.

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/124876/6573

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but maybe my case is different: I have a certification file of the user and I want to sign some information with it to certify the user is associated with it, and save only this p7s file on the server after all. I would not like to send the user's certificate to the server because it would be insecure for a decentralised application. Do you think it's impossible to sign on the client-side?